# Query event - Range limit on Polygon, but not on Ethereum?

Tags: events, polygon, query

I want to query some deposit events to show all deposits for a user.

On Ethereum, I did it like this to query all deposits (starting from block 0)

```
const block = await provider.getBlockNumber()
const depositStream = await exchange.queryFilter("Deposit", 0, block)
```

Now I deployed the same smart contract and frontend to Polygon and I get the following error:

```
block range is too wide
```

To get this to work I have to limit the range to like 3000 blocks:

```
const depositStream = await exchange.queryFilter("Deposit", block - 3000, block)
```

But this will only give me the data of the last 3000 blocks, so like 2 hours. Deposits from a couple of days ago will not show up.

What would be a good approach to query all data on Polygon?